# Find Consecutive error in file and list file names

Tags: shell-script, shell

I got this project to analysis my logs where I need to find any consecutive errors occurred more then thrice and list logs name. As my logs were huge, I wrote below script:

```
for i in `ls`  
  do 
  count=`uniq -c $i | grep 'FATAL ERROR' |sed 's/^ *//g'| sed 's/ /,/g' | awk -F',' '{if($1 >1) {print $1}}'`  
  if [[ $count -ge 2 ]]  
  then  
    echo $i  
  fi  
done
```

This works if you just need to know number of occurrence in which all file

```
grep -o -c Source * | awk -F: '{if ($2 > 2){print $1}}'
```

What could have been the better version of my script? What if log is really huge, my piece of code will slowdown.

Comment: [Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead) and [use `$()` instead of backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: @RoVo, Thanks a lot for your suggestion .

Comment: If you're using `-ge 2` you'll trigger on two or more. Your question uses "thrice" which means three times. Which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Pipelines should generally be kept short, and most of the things that you do to get the value for `count` could be done in a single `awk` program, including the loop and the `if` statement.

```
awk 'FNR == 1 || !/FATAL ERROR/ { count = 0 }
     /FATAL ERROR/              { ++count }
     count == 2                 { print FILENAME }' ./*
```

This runs a single `awk` program across all non-hidden files in the current directory.

The program will reset its `count` variable to zero if we're at the first line of a new file *or* if the current line does not match the pattern `FATAL ERROR`.

If the line matches the pattern `FATAL ERROR`, the `count` variable is incremented.

If the `count` variable reaches a value of 2, the name of the current file is printed.

The code will print the name of the file each time it finds two consecutive lines that matches the pattern, even if this happens multiple times in the same file.  If this in not wanted, you could expand the code slightly:

```
awk 'FNR == 1       { count = 0; do_print = 1 }
     !/FATAL ERROR/ { count = 0 }
     /FATAL ERROR/  { ++count }
     count == 2 && do_print { print FILENAME; do_print = 0 }' ./*
```

or with GNU `awk` (using `nextfile` to skip to the next file):

```
awk 'FNR == 1 || !/FATAL ERROR/ { count = 0 }
     /FATAL ERROR/              { ++count }
     count == 2 && do_print     { print FILENAME; nextfile }' ./*
```

Related to your shell loop:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead)

Comment: Finding it hard to understand , but still trying :)